# How to add different functions for the buttons generated using a for loop in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

In flutter, I need to generate some buttons. I generated buttons using for the loop, But in this case, I am not able to add different functions to each button generated using for loop. I need to give different functions to each button.

Comment: You could create an array with all the functions with the same index as your buttons

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to perform a function corresponding to a condition given a condition.

```
 int _containerNumber = 0;

  ///Create Button
  _customTextButton(int num) {
    setState(() {
      switch (num) {
        case 0:
          _containerNumber = 0;
          break;
        case 1:
          _containerNumber = 1;
          break;
        case 2:
          _containerNumber = 2;
          break;
        case 3:
          _containerNumber = 3;
          break;
        default:
          _containerNumber = 0;
      }
    });
  }

  _changeColor() {
    switch (_containerNumber) {
      case 0:
        return Colors.grey;
      case 1:
        return Colors.red;
      case 2:
        return Colors.green;
      case 3:
        return Colors.blue;
      default:
        return Colors.grey;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('test'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _containerNumber != 0
              ? Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 50,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: _changeColor(),
                  child: Text('Clicked Button$_containerNumber'),
                )
              : SizedBox(),
          for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            TextButton(
              child: Text('Button'),
              onPressed: () => _customTextButton(i),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: I need to change the container color according to the selected and unselected, the container which is generated using the for loop.

Comment: Assume you have three buttons. When each button is clicked, should the color of the container change according to the button clicked?

Comment: Actually, I need to generate the container and as per the click on the container, the container color should change.

Comment: Edited the answer. Is this what you want? Click the button to change the container's appearance.

Comment: yes but the container is also generated by using the for loop

Comment: I think your problem is now solved. Please check the edited answer